Consulta de como puedo hacer una llamada entre soluciones en C#
Hola debo hacer un programa que tenga subprograma o solución estaran hecho en winform en C# con framework 4.8, en total son 8 soluciones, de las cuales 3 son DLL, entre ella una de conexion, otra de enciptracion y otra de seguridad,  5 subprograma, que seria el programa base de lo cuales llamara y ejecutara los demas 4 soluciones o subprograma, la consulta es como se llaman, los DLL se deben integrar a la solucion que deseo ocupar el DLL y usando Using DLL  esta listo, se que debo integrarlo en la solucion que deseo ocupar, pero como se llama para que se abra y se ejecute .
Gracias
